# How Jax use LAX-backend implementation of functions

Tags: python, jax

I need to compute the kron procuts of two arrays and I want to test if doing it using Jax is faster than doing it using Numpy.

Now, in numpy my code there is `res = numpy.kron(x1,x2)`, in Jax there is `jax.numpy.kron(x1,x2)` but how can I use it properly?
My doubs are:

- is it sufficient to replace `numpy` with `jax.numpy` as follows: `res = jax.numpy.kron(x1,x2)`?
- should I first sent x1 and x2 to the device using `x1_dev = jax.device_put(x1)` and after that run `res = jax.numpy.kron(x1_dev,x2_dev)`?
- should I add `jax.block_until_ready()` to the `jax.numpy.kron()` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in JAX's FAQ under [Benchmarking JAX Code](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#benchmarking-jax-code).

In particular, if you're interested in the speed of JAX vs NumPy I would read the second section of this, [Is JAX Faster Than Numpy?](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#is-jax-faster-than-numpy) which gives a broad overview of when you should expect JAX to be faster or slower than equivalent NumPy code.

As for benchmarking `kron`: following the advice there, I would benchmark them like this (using IPython's [`%timeit`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) for convenience). I ran the following on a Colab T4 GPU runtime:

```py
import numpy as np
x1 = np.random.rand(1000)
x2 = np.random.rand(1000)
%timeit np.kron(x1, x2)
```

```
6.52 ms ± 580 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
x1_jax = jnp.array(x1)
x2_jax = jnp.array(x2)
%timeit jnp.kron(x1_jax, x2_jax).block_until_ready()
```

```
1.39 ms ± 2.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

If you want to see the effect of just-in-time compilation with `jax.jit`, you can do something like this:

```py
import jax
jit_kron = jax.jit(jnp.kron)
_ = jit_kron(x1_jax, x2_jax)  # trigger compilation before timing
%timeit jit_kron(x1_jax, x2_jax).block_until_ready()
```

```
116 µs ± 33.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: but can I collect the result in the same way I do in numpy? so `res = jnp.kron(x1_jax,x2_jax).block_until_ready()`

Comment: You only need `block_until_ready()` when running micro-benchmarks. If you just want to call the function and get the result, use `result = jnp.kron(x1, x2)` and the inputs can be either NumPy arrays (`x1, x2`) or JAX arrays (`x1_jax1, x2_jax`).